# Create new column of from list using each item's name

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a list of dataframes. I'd like to loop through them using `purrr` and do some analysis. Part of the analysis includes renaming a variable according to the name of the list item. This allows me to properly merge the files into a single dataframe. I'm a bit stuck as to how to go about accomplishing this.

```
    library(tidyverse)

# Get names of columns

df <- mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  select(1:5)

mtcars_names <- df %>% 
  names()

# Split into many dataframes based on columns
mtcars_ls <- df %>% 
  gather(key, value) %>%
  split(.$key)


map2(mtcars_ls, mtcars_names, function(x, y){
  x %>% 
    rename(y = value)
})
#> $cyl
#> # A tibble: 32 x 2
#>    key       y
#>    <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 cyl       6
#>  2 cyl       6
#>  3 cyl       4
#>  4 cyl       6
#>  5 cyl       8
#>  6 cyl       6
#>  7 cyl       8
#>  8 cyl       4
#>  9 cyl       4
#> 10 cyl       6
#> # … with 22 more rows
#> 
#> $disp
#> # A tibble: 32 x 2
#>    key       y
#>    <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 disp   160 
#>  2 disp   160 
#>  3 disp   108 
#>  4 disp   258 
#>  5 disp   360 
#>  6 disp   225 
#>  7 disp   360 
#>  8 disp   147.
#>  9 disp   141.
#> 10 disp   168.
#> # … with 22 more rows
#> 
#> $drat
#> # A tibble: 32 x 2
#>    key       y
#>    <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 drat   3.9 
#>  2 drat   3.9 
#>  3 drat   3.85
#>  4 drat   3.08
#>  5 drat   3.15
#>  6 drat   2.76
#>  7 drat   3.21
#>  8 drat   3.69
#>  9 drat   3.92
#> 10 drat   3.92
#> # … with 22 more rows
#> 
#> $hp
#> # A tibble: 32 x 2
#>    key       y
#>    <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 hp      110
#>  2 hp      110
#>  3 hp       93
#>  4 hp      110
#>  5 hp      175
#>  6 hp      105
#>  7 hp      245
#>  8 hp       62
#>  9 hp       95
#> 10 hp      123
#> # … with 22 more rows
#> 
#> $mpg
#> # A tibble: 32 x 2
#>    key       y
#>    <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 mpg    21  
#>  2 mpg    21  
#>  3 mpg    22.8
#>  4 mpg    21.4
#>  5 mpg    18.7
#>  6 mpg    18.1
#>  7 mpg    14.3
#>  8 mpg    24.4
#>  9 mpg    22.8
#> 10 mpg    19.2
#> # … with 22 more rows
Created on 2019-09-03 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```

Comment: (upvote) I actually asked myself this question 15 minutes ago but from a different angle

Comment: @PaulEndymion I actually do this a lot too -- never figured out a concise way to do it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's actually a nice function in `purrr` called `imap` that seems to do just what you need. It iterates over both the elements (`.x`) and the names (`.y`) of the list:

```
df <- mtcars %>% 
  select(1:5)

# Split into many dataframes based on columns and create a named list
mtcars_ls <- df %>% 
  gather(key, value) %>%
  split(.$key) %>% 
  set_names(names(df))

imap(mtcars_ls, function(x,y) {
  x %>% 
    rename(!!quo_name(y) := value)
})
```

The `!!quo_name` and `:=` are to allow the name strings to be tidy evaluated. To make that even simpler you could use the shorthand notation:

```
imap(mtcars_ls, ~ rename(.x, !!quo_name(.y) := value))
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use `rename_at`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

map2(mtcars_ls, mtcars_names, function(x, y){
    x %>% rename_at(vars(value), ~y) %>% head
})

#$cyl
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  key     mpg
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 cyl       6
#2 cyl       6
#3 cyl       4
#4 cyl       6
#5 cyl       8
#6 cyl       6

#$disp
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  key     cyl
#  <chr>  <dbl>
#1 disp    160
#2 disp    160
#3 disp    108
#4 disp    258
#5 disp    360
#6 disp    225
#....
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution generating your code case by case as text to then evaluate it:

```r
library(tidyverse)


# Get names of columns

df <- mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  select(1:5)

mtcars_names <- df %>% 
  names()

# Split into many dataframes based on columns
mtcars_ls <- df %>% 
  gather(key, value) %>%
  split(.$key)


map2(mtcars_ls, mtcars_names, function(x, y){
  eval(parse(text = paste0('rename(x,',y,' = value)')))
})
#> $cyl
#> # A tibble: 32 x 2
#>    key     mpg
#>    <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 cyl       6
#>  2 cyl       6
#>  3 cyl       4
#>  4 cyl       6
#>  5 cyl       8
#>  6 cyl       6
#>  7 cyl       8
#>  8 cyl       4
#>  9 cyl       4
#> 10 cyl       6
#> # … with 22 more rows
#> 
#> $disp
#> # A tibble: 32 x 2
#>    key     cyl
#>    <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 disp   160 
#>  2 disp   160 
#>  3 disp   108 
#>  4 disp   258 
#>  5 disp   360 
#>  6 disp   225 
#>  7 disp   360 
#>  8 disp   147.
#>  9 disp   141.
#> 10 disp   168.
#> # … with 22 more rows
#> 
#> $drat
#> # A tibble: 32 x 2
#>    key    disp
#>    <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 drat   3.9 
#>  2 drat   3.9 
#>  3 drat   3.85
#>  4 drat   3.08
#>  5 drat   3.15
#>  6 drat   2.76
#>  7 drat   3.21
#>  8 drat   3.69
#>  9 drat   3.92
#> 10 drat   3.92
#> # … with 22 more rows
#> 
#> $hp
#> # A tibble: 32 x 2
#>    key      hp
#>    <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 hp      110
#>  2 hp      110
#>  3 hp       93
#>  4 hp      110
#>  5 hp      175
#>  6 hp      105
#>  7 hp      245
#>  8 hp       62
#>  9 hp       95
#> 10 hp      123
#> # … with 22 more rows
#> 
#> $mpg
#> # A tibble: 32 x 2
#>    key    drat
#>    <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 mpg    21  
#>  2 mpg    21  
#>  3 mpg    22.8
#>  4 mpg    21.4
#>  5 mpg    18.7
#>  6 mpg    18.1
#>  7 mpg    14.3
#>  8 mpg    24.4
#>  9 mpg    22.8
#> 10 mpg    19.2
#> # … with 22 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I would heavily advise not doing this

Comment: @Shinobi_Atobe Would you be so kind as to tell us why? So that i know what to avoid in future.

Comment: It is difficult to read and to understand what is going on, there are pre existing fucntions that do the same thing and parsing strings as function names is a bad way to learn R, especially in the world of Non Standard Evaluation